# Order of the largest cyclic subgroup of $Z_6 \times Z_{10} \times Z_{15}$

Tags: group-theory

$\mathbb{Z}_6 \times \mathbb{Z}_{10} \times \mathbb{Z}_{15}$ has a cyclic subgroup of order $30$ which is $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_{5} \times \mathbb{Z}_{3}$.

Is it the largest or not?

Comment: If you pick any element $g=(a,b,c)$ it must satisfy $g^{30}=1$, so there cannot be any larger cyclic subgroups.

Comment: You might be very interested in learning about the [standard forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitely_generated_abelian_group#Classification) for finite abelian groups, and how to put groups into those standard forms. The largest invariant factor, in particular, is the largest cyclic subgroup of a finite abelian group.

Answer (score 1):

Using that $\;C_n\times C_m=C_{nm}\;$ for coprime $\;n,m\;$ , you can write

$$C_6\times C_{10}\times C_{15}=C_2\times C_3\times C_2\times C_5\times C_3\times C_5=C_{30}\times C_{30}$$

and now it is much clearer, in my opinion, that for any $\;a\in G:=C_{30}\times C_{30}\;$ we have that $\;a^{30}=1\;$ , so yes: the maximal cyclic subgroup of $\;G\;$ is of order $\;30\;$ .